# Как выбрать из базы определенное количество слов?

Tags: php, mysql

На страницу загружается конфиг, в котором прописано:

```
$shortText = '$value["description"]';
$mystring = mb_substr($shortText,0,11);
```

Потом:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tasks';
$sqlInquiry = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
while ($value = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlInquiry) ){
 $tasks[] = $value;
}
```

После чего:

```
<?php foreach ($tasks as $value): ?>
           <h2><a href="singlTask.php?id=<?=$value['id']?>"><?=$value['title']?></a></h2>
             <p><?=$mystring?></p>
         </div>
     </li>
 <?php endforeach;?>
```

В результате выводится текст: `$value["description"]`, если убираю одинарные скобки - пустота.

Comment: Все действия выполняются последовательно, если вы в начале присвоили чему то значение переменной $value[xxx], то там будет лежать то значение которое было в ней на момент присвоения. А то ч в ней окажется позже в цикле будет в ней позже и уже никак не повлияет на ту переменную которой вы присваивали что то ранее. А уж про кавычки ... откройте первые страницы какого нибудь руководства по азам php. там написано, что текст в одинарных кавычках не интерполируется и представляется "как есть", а в двойных - интерполируются имена переменных и их содержимое (на данный момент) кладется в текст

Answer (score 0):

А если так:

```
$mystring = mb_substr($$shortText,0,11);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Получилось так:**

```
<?=mb_substr($value['description'],0,10,'UTF-8');?></p>
```